# PHP Google API Client v3 get contacts

Tags: php, xml-parsing, google-api, google-api-php-client

I still have trouble with the new google_api_client php library. I'm trying to retrieve the user's contacts.

I'm very close to the right solution ... I mean, I just got all the results but a can't parse it.

Probably it's because I'm not strong with XML parser. After tests and tests ... I get this solution (based on the example file by Google):

```
...
$req = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");         
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$response = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());

foreach($response->entry as $entry)
{
    $child = $entry->children("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005");
    $mail_info = $child->attributes();
}
...
```

In the $response I can get the title field where my contact's full name is stored, and in the $mail_info a got an object where i see the address field when I get the email address.

It's SAD and UGLY solution ... what if I want the company name, address ... phone numbers ... photos. Where are all these informations.

How can I use the Google response in a great and clean solution?

Anyone can give me some help.
Bye

Answer (score 6):

What helped me was requesting JSON instead of XML. Try adding `?alt=json` to the end of the URL in the request you make to google.

```
$req = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json");         
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$string = $val->getResponseBody();
$phparray = json_decode($string);
```

Certainly not child's play to get what you want but working with php arrays is probably easier.

For completeness this is the [google contacts php example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/contacts/simple.php) that we both probably found that helped us:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/contacts/simple.php

**EDIT:**

Here is another link that might help. In the comments it describes a cleaner of accessing contact's data using JSON.

http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);

$temp = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);

foreach($temp['feed']['entry'] as $cnt) {
    echo $cnt['title']['$t'] . " --- " . $cnt['gd$email']['0']['address'] . "</br>";
}
```

and

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);

$temp = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);

foreach($temp['feed']['entry'] as $cnt) {
    echo $cnt['title']['$t'] . " --- " . $cnt['gd$email']['0']['address'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$phoneNumber'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$street'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$street']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$neighborhood'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$neighborhood']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$pobox'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$pobox']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$postcode'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$postcode']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$city'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$city']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$region'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$region']['$t'];
    if(isset($cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$country'])) echo " --- " . $cnt['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$country']['$t'];
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: works great if you use file_get_contents instead of curl_file_get_contents